# Implementing conditional formatting

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have a set of tolerance values in the 11th and 13th row of each column. I have data from row 21 to row 118 that I want to conditional format high and low. High is red, low is yellow. This is part of a larger macro that copies data out of a workbook, closes it and pastes the data into a new workbook. I need someone to point out why my code won't select the cells I'm trying to.

Here is some example data

1

2 Max

3 4787

4 Min

5 2331

6 Spec

7 3250

8 Tolerance

9 750

10 Hi Spec

11 4000

12 Low Spec

13 2500

14

15

16

17 Failed

18 31

19

20 Data

21 3947

...

118 4409

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 7 To 13

    Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(i, 21), Cells(i, 118)).Select

    Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(i, 21), Cells(i, 118)).FormatConditions.Add 
        Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
            Formula1:=Cells(i, 11)

Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
      .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
          .Color = 255
          .TintAndShade = 0
    End With



    Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(i, 21), Cells(i, 118)).FormatConditions.Add 
         Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
           Formula1:=Cells(i, 13)

Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority

    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
       .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
       .ColorIndex = 6
       .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
      'i=i+1 fragment from previous code, deleted (please ignore)
```

### Next

### Please use this code as a learning exercise, the correct method is below

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 7 To 13

Range(Cells(21, i), Cells(118, i)).Select

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:=Cells(11, i)

With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
 End With


 Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, _
      Formula1:=Cells(13, i)

 Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
   .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
   .ColorIndex = 6
   .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

Next
```

Comment: Can you post some example data?

Comment: I see you are incrementing "i" near the bottom. Is that intentional? You already are using a For-Loop that automatically increments "i".

Comment: FYI, if you want "i" to increment by 2 each loop you can do,
For i = 7 to 13 step 2